# SwitchMap: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>' for http response

Tags: angular, rxjs

I using rxjs v. 6.4.0 and am trying to use `switchMap` to pass the value of my observable to another observable but am getting the error `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'`.

```
 getFoodOrder(id : number): Observable<IFoodOrder> {
    let url = `${ this.baseUrl }/food_orders/${ id }`
    return this.http.get<IFoodOrder>(url)
  }

  this.foodOrderProvider.getFoodOrder(1)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(data => console.log(data)) // <-- error occurs here
    ).subscribe(() => console.log("done"))
```

What am I missing?  `getFoodOrder` returns an observable.

Comment: The error is correct. The projection function for `switchMap` always needs to return an Observable (or Observable-like value). You're not returning anything thus it throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

console.log() does not return anything hence the error. Returning data after logging will resolve the error.

```
 switchMap(data =>  { console.log(data) return of(data)});
```

If you only want to log the data, better use `tap` operator, just for looking at the data.

```
this.foodOrderProvider.getFoodOrder(1)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(data))
    ).subscribe(() => console.log("done"))
```

Comment: ohhhh, I thought it was the input, not the return there!  makes a ton of sense now

Comment: hmm.. It's still showing the error?  Is that because it's not an observable?

Comment: Generally it should still work, but yes switchMap in typescript will expect observable, so using `of(data)` can do the trick.